# landscaping plant in yard

Tags: identification, bulbs

i have dark green clumps in my yard that look like grass but when pulled there are bulbs attached almost like little onions. The green part and bulbs do not have any distinct fragrance.

Comment: Could you post a picture?  What area do you live in?

Comment: Have you seen any flowers on these plants? If so, what did they look like?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Once you give us more details, someone should be able to help figure out what plant you have. You can just press on the gray "edit" button or this [edit] and add the answers to our questions and anything else you can think of right into your question! Check our [help] pages to learn more about us, and leave a comment here if you need help with anything! Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if it's in the [grape hyacinth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscari_latifolium) family. I have lots of them. [This page](http://www.guide-to-houseplants.com/grape-hyacinths.html) has a drawing showing what the bulb looks like. That would depend, though, especially on the flower, so it's just a thought at the moment!

Comment: Sounds like it could be either [Onion Weed](https://www.google.com/search?q=onion+weed&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS664US664&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5wI7vipzMAhVNwWMKHSL-DVUQ_AUIBygB&biw=1920&bih=979) or possibly even [Star of Bethlehem](https://www.google.com/search?q=Star+of+Bethlehem&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS664US664&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig_NnTipzMAhUPz2MKHVeSBowQ_AUIBygB&biw=1920&bih=979#tbm=isch&q=star+of+bethlehem+weed&imgrc=7O80KVBx2tVTYM%3A) if it has white flowers.

Comment: Many, many flowering bulbs fit this description. Leave them alone and you might find out what type of flower they are.

Comment: Please update your question and specifically ask the question you are trying to get answered.  It seems that you are asking for help in identifying the plant and if so state it in so many words.  Pictures would help as well

Comment: Sounds like sedge.https://www.google.com/search?q=sedge+roots&rlz=1C1QJDB_en&espv=2&biw=1067&bih=540&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigid6D3rvQAhUY92MKHWMIDJcQ7AkIKQ  Check this out.